# Uninstalling a weird and new app

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, software-uninstall, unity-tweak-tool

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I wanted to install Unity-tweak-tool, but a few seconds after it began installing I canceled the installation and then an app was added to my launcher and it's mostly like "nautilus" with the name "Files" and a purple icon and different customization and background.

I want to uninstall it or at least remove its icon. I have searched "unity-tweak-tool", "Files" and in `/usr/share/applications` for its icon to remove and the command: `dpkg --list`, but none of them exist.

The app's icon and name:

[image: The apps icon and name]

The left one is this new app and right one is nautilus:

[image: Left one is this new app and right is nautilus]

Comment: It seems to be `nemo`, a file manager that replaces nautilus in other Ubuntu flavours. Check if `nemo` package is present in your system. However, I have no idea how you installed It while installing unity-tweak-tool (the correct package name is `gnome-tweaks`)

Comment: Thank you very much that was correct the name of this app was "nemo" and i just uninstalled it. but there is no "gnome-tweaks" between the packages even though there is a package nemed: "unity-tweak-tool", my question is that it is the same "unity-tweak-tool" i wanted to install at first? i mean can i uninstall it? woulden't it remove importatnt tools?

Comment: Ubuntu does not use anymore Unity as Desktop enviroment, but switched to GNOME. `unity-tweak-tool` has been replaced by `gnome-tweak-tool` (correct name) that is the same tool. They are quite the same tool.

Comment: If you didn't install the old Unity DE, you can remove `unity-tweak-tool` and install `gnome-tweak-tool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package that you installed is Nemo, that is a file manager (born as fork of Nautilus) and that is used in some Ubuntu flavours like Ubuntu Budgie. Also Linux Mint uses it.

I don't know which kind of dependencies brought you to install it, but you can remove it by: (flag suggested in a comment by [@AkibAzmain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269275/uninstalling-a-weird-and-new-app#comment2149113_1269288))

```bsh
sudo apt remove --autoremove nemo
```